# Finding process count in Linux via command line

Tags: linux, command-line, process, count

I was looking for the best way to find the number of running processes with the same name via the command line in Linux. For example if I wanted to find the number of bash processes running and get "5". Currently I have a script that does a 'pidof ' and then does a count on the tokenized string. This works fine but I was wondering if there was a better way that can be done entirely via the command line. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is there a way to get a rolling count, especially of the number of tasks which match a specific string? Something like `top | grep TaskName | wc -l`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

On Linux systems (and perhaps some non-Linux systems as well) that have `pgrep` available, the `-c`/`--count` option returns a count of the number of processes that match the given name:

```
pgrep --count command_name
```

If `pgrep` is not available, you may be able to use `ps` and `wc`. Again this may be somewhat system-dependent, but on typical Linux systems the following command will get you a count of processes:

```
ps -C command_name -e --no-headers | wc -l
```

The `-C` option to `ps` takes `command_name` as an argument, and the program prints a table of information about processes whose executable name matches the given command name. `-e` causes it to search processes owned by all users, not just the calling user. The `--no-headers` option suppresses the headers of the table, which are normally printed as the first line. With `--no-headers`, you get one line per process matched. Then `wc -l` counts and prints the number of lines in its input.

There are a few key differences between these commands:

- `pgrep` uses `grep`-style matching, so e.g. `pgrep sh` will also match `bash` processes. If you want an exact match, also use the `-x`/`--exact` option. On the other hand, `ps -C` uses exact matching, not `grep`-style.
- `ps` will output a row for itself and/or any other process it's being piped to, if those match the process selection criteria you gave. So `ps -C ps --no-headers | wc -l` and `ps -C wc --no-headers | wc -l` will always output at least 1, because they are counting themselves. On the other hand, `pgrep` excludes itself. So `pgrep --count pgrep` will output 0 unless there are other separate `pgrep` processes running. (Typically the `pgrep` behavior is what you want, which is why I generally recommend using `pgrep` if it's available.)

Here's a summary of a few variations:

| Use case | pgrep | ps |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Exact match | `pgrep -x -c command_name` | `ps -C command_name -e --no-headers | wc -l` |
| Substring match | `pgrep -c command_name` | N/A |
| Only current user | `pgrep -U "$UID" -c command_name` | `ps -C command_name --no-headers | wc -l` |

There are many more possibilities, too many to list here. Check the man pages for `pgrep` and `ps` if you need different behavior, and you might find an option that implements it.

Comment: Wiping out the headers is good for some reason, when I run ps there's 2 processes and when I run `ps --no-headers | wc -l` there's 3 processes. It seems to count the initial newline?

Comment: Hmm, looks like `pgrep -c` is not an option on OpenBSD / Darwin. Could you add a little explanation of why you've selected those flags ( for both commands ) ? Without some explanation it makes it tough for users on a different distro to even use a `man` page to try and translate your intentions...

Comment: Simple `ps --no-headers | wc -l` gives me 4 instead of 3 processes (that you'd see under `ps --no-headers`). What might be the case here?

Comment: @krzemian hard to say without seeing what the processes are.

Comment: @DavidZ Try `ps >> test`, then see if `wc -l test` and `ps | wc -l` give the same results. In my case they differ by 1, which bugs me (like a lot).

Comment: @krzemian Sorry I didn't see this at the time! In case it's still relevant: the difference is probably coming from the `wc` process, which is listed in the output of `ps` when you have them running in parallel in a pipeline, but not when you just dump the `ps` output to a file and run `wc` on it later. I added a note about that to the answer.

Answer (score 11):

```
result=`ps -Al | grep command-name | wc -l`
echo $result
```

Answer (score 8):

```
ps -Al | grep -c bash
```

Answer (score 6):

**You can try :**

```
ps -ef | grep -cw [p]rocess_name
```

OR

```
ps aux | grep -cw [p]rocess_name
```

**For e.g.,:**

```
ps -ef | grep -cw [i]nit
```

Comment: I like how simple and clean this solution is

Answer (score 3):

Some of the above didn't work for me, but they helped me on my way to this.

```
ps aux | grep [j]ava -c
```

For newbies to Linux:

`ps aux` prints all the currently running processes, `grep` searches for all processes that match the word *java*, the `[]` brackets remove the process you just ran so it wont include that as a running process and finally the `-c` option stands for count.

Answer (score 3):

List all process names, sort and count

```
ps --no-headers -A -o comm | sort | uniq -c
```

You also can list process attached to a tty

```
ps --no-headers a -o comm | sort | uniq -c
```

You may filter with:

```
ps --no-headers -A -o comm | awk '{ list[$1] ++ } END { for (i in list) { if (list[i] > 10) printf ("%20s: %s\n", i, list[i]) } }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Following bash script can be run as a cron job and you can possibly get email if any process forks itself too much.

```
for i in `ps -A -o comm= --sort=+comm | uniq`; 
do 
    if (( `ps -C $i --no-headers | wc -l` > 10 )); then 
        echo `hostname` $i `ps -C $i --no-headers | wc -l` ;
    fi
done
```

Replace 10 with your number of concern.

TODO: "10" could be passed as command line parameter as well. Also, few system processes can be put into exception list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ps`(will show snapshot of processes) with `wc`(will count number of words, `wc -l` option will count lines i.e. newline characters).
Which is very easy and simple to remember.

`ps -e | grep processName | wc -l`

This simple command will print number of processes running on current server.
If you want to find the number of process running on current server for current user then use `-U` option of `ps`.

`ps -U root | grep processName | wc -l`

change root with username.

But as mentioned in lot of other answers you can also use `ps -e | grep -c process_name` which is more elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

> `ps aux | wc -l`

This command shows number of processes running on the system by all the users.

For a specific user you can use the following command:

> `ps -u <username> | wc -l`

replace  with the actual username before running :)

Answer (score 0):

> ps -awef | grep CAP | wc -l

Here "CAP" is the word which is in the my Process_Names.

This command output =  Number of Processes + 1

This is why When we are running this command , our system read thats "ps -awef | grep CAP | wc -l " is also a process.

So yes our real answer is (Number of Processes) = Command Output - 1

Note : These processes are only those processes who include the name of "CAP"