# Using grep and wc to search and count matching processes

Tags: unix, grep, ps, wc

I am using ps to list all of the processes running on the machine I am connected to, searching them for my own processes, and then printing the number of processes I am running, like so:

`ps -Af | grep '^mkuhlman' | wc -l`

Problem is, checking against the actual list of processes, I'm only running 8, but `wc` is listing 9 processes. What am I doing wrong?

To clarify, I am not looking for matches to processes, but matches to my own username.

Comment: `ps .. | grep '^[m]kuhlman' | wc -l` although the "wrong" way (which you'll see every day) is `ps .. | grep ... | grep -v grep | wc -l` . Good luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding process count in Linux via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058137/finding-process-count-in-linux-via-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

Your pipeline has a few processes, and you're counting them.

Running `ps` is fine, but you might be happier with `pgrep`. It has a man page. (And `ps -A` seems at odds with grepping for your own username.)

Comment: Unfortunately, my teacher wants us to use these specific commands. I've looked through all our notes and the man pages for each, and I can't seem to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Consider doing `ps -Af  > /tmp/proc`. Then you don't need to worry about grep < proc or grep -v ps or wc or whatever processing pipeline showing up in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Though `grep -v grep` would work in most cases, it can result in wrong output as it excludes all `grep` processes, not just the ones related to the `ps` command line.  So, you could do this instead:

```
ps -Af | grep -E '^mkuhlman|__unique__' | grep -v __unique__
```

where `__unique__` is a unique string that is unlikely to be used in the command line of other user processes.

---

See also:

- [Finding process count in Linux via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058137/finding-process-count-in-linux-via-command-line)