# java jvisualvm can not see the local JVM processes

Tags: java, jvisualvm

I stop seeing the local JVM processes in jvisualvm. I definitely have [JVM processes running](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17681313/432903) which I can verify with `ps` command.

```
$ ps aux | grep java -c
10
```

Here's empty jvisualvm window,

[image: emprt jvisualvm]

I tried adding JMX agent `localhost:3333` as mentioned in this [oracle article - Java VisualVM - Connecting to JMX Agents Explicitly](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/jmx_connections.html). But I get `can not connect to localhost:3333 using service:jmx`

I see the processes in jconsole however.

[image]

Comment: I recommend switching to JMC if possible. I've encountered many bugs with VisualVM ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052961/prevent-program-from-crashing-when-showing-allocation-stack-traces)), and JMC comes bundled with the JDK.

Comment: interesting. I was using `jvisualvm` for a while measuring perf of my app. The visual looked pretty good but now can even see the processes anymore. I actually started with `jmc` found it bit complicated than `jvisualvm`. But after your comment went back to `jmc` provides Memory/ Threads/JVM CPU usage. Thats all I care. Please you can post your comment as an answer with some desricption.

Comment: I just realized you are using Tomcat. Did you specify the [required configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1915846/2398375) to enable JMX?

Answer (score 2):

Open VisualVm -> Window -> Application

Local JVM processes panel should appear on the left, with the same list of processes that JConsole shows