# How to count how many instances of a program are running in the system using python

Tags: python, multiple-instances, kali-linux

I would like to know how I can count how many instances of a program are running in the system using python.

For example: if my terminal is open 3 "times", and there are 3 instances of the terminal, how could I count them using python ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I mean, if you're on Linux you can just use a Linux command to do it, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058137/finding-process-count-in-linux-via-command-line), and then bring the results into Python; are you saying you'd rather invent your own way of getting the count of process/command instances? Why?

Comment: You could potentially use [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) to get processes and the names of the executing programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is fairly very straightforward if one uses the `psutil` package in `python3`

Consider the code snippet below.

```
import psutil
from collections import Counter

process_ctr = Counter()

for process in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        process_cmd_list = process.cmdline()
        for p in process_cmd_list:
            process_ctr[p] += 1
    except Exception:
        continue

for pname, cnt in process_ctr.items():
    print(pname, cnt)
```

Upon running this code, one will get the process name and count printed to `stdout`

Testing: I opened 3 terminals and I noticed this in the O/P: `-bash 3`

Sample O/P:

```
--pdf-renderer 2
--js-flags=--jitless 2
--renderer-client-id=657 1
--launch-time-ticks=75930041264 1
--renderer-client-id=658 1
--launch-time-ticks=76065123981 1
--seatbelt-client=151 4
--renderer-client-id=659 1
--launch-time-ticks=76065777110 1
--renderer-client-id=663 1
--launch-time-ticks=76077686392 1
--renderer-client-id=100 1
--launch-time-ticks=1656826210 1
--renderer-client-id=665 1
--launch-time-ticks=76250675532 1
--seatbelt-client=168 11
--renderer-client-id=666 1
--launch-time-ticks=76252057630 1
-bash 3
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreFollowUp.framework/Versions/A/Support/followupd 1
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/Support/photoanalysisd 1
/System/Library/CoreServices/ScopedBookmarkAgent 1
--renderer-client-id=672 1
--launch-time-ticks=76542560240 1
--renderer-client-id=676 1
--launch-time-ticks=76557205901 1
```

Note:

1. The `try`, `catch` is needed as `psutil` cannot access some process details, as they are owned by the kernel.

Based on user feedback, adding some neat code, just to get the count for the process of interest.

```
import psutil
from collections import Counter

process_ctr = Counter()

def get_process_count(pname):
    for process in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            process_cmd_list = process.cmdline()
            for p in process_cmd_list:
                process_ctr[p] += 1
        except Exception:
            continue

    for p, cnt in process_ctr.items():
        if pname in p:
            return cnt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cnt = get_process_count('qterminal')
    print(f"The cnt is:{cnt}")
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, that was more helpful than you can imagine. But more precisely, could you also tell me how I can make it so that my code returns how many instances of the terminal (aka /usr/bin/qterminal 3) are open, sorry if it's kind of stupid question, I'm a beginner in using Python.

Comment: Hi @Meaks. I have updated the code based on your suggestion. Give it a shot, and let me know if it works. I tested it locally for my `bash` terminal.

Comment: Also, if you are all set, please mark this answer as "Accepted". @Meaks

Answer (score 0):

The example provided by tenacity works well except if no instances exist matching `pname` then it returns `None` and the counter would count up every time it was executed so moved it into the function call.
Stackedoverflow has **too many pending edits** so posting an copy of it instead of editing:

```
from collections import Counter
from psutil import AccessDenied, process_iter


def get_process_count(pname: str) -> int:
    process_ctr = Counter()
    for process in process_iter():
        try:
            process_cmd_list = process.cmdline()
            for p in process_cmd_list:
                process_ctr[p] += 1
        except AccessDenied:
            pass
    for p, cnt in process_ctr.items():
        if pname in p:
            return cnt
    return 0
```